# Microsoft ODBC driver for Linux vs FreeTDS?

Tags: sql-server, linux, freetds, unixodbc

I am investigating the possibilities to connect to a MSSQL database from a RHEL6 application server. I have found two ways:

- [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org)
- [Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160) + [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/)

Does anyone have experience in using either of these setups? (I'm especially curious about the latter, since it is officially supported by MS). Performance? Stability? Any other options I might be missing?

Comment: Are you still using FreeTDS in 2019? I've been using it since 2014, mainly without issues, but I'm curious about Microsoft's drivers. Their recent docs look very useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: No, not using it anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, I went with FreeTDS at the moment. I evaluated both unixODBC and FreeTDS and found FreeTDS easier to work with at the moment.

Comment: Would you care to expand on this answer?  I also want to know the differences between the two options you provided in your question.  How or in what way is FreeTDS easier to work with?

Comment: I found the documentation better, the APIs easier to start with and maybe most important, installation and deployment a lot easier. A big plus is that I can also read and understand the source code for FreeTDS.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the [MS JDBC driver for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. True, I should have written that the interface with the driver will be written in C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with older versions of SQL Server (e.g. 2000), current Microsoft ODBC drivers may not work.

FreeTDS claims to work with all versions of MS SQL Server:
http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#Does.FreeTDS.support.my.server